# How to get values from different rows from one column to separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| app_id | service_name | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | service_1 | res_json |
| 100 | service_2 | res_json |
| 100 | service_3 | res_json |
| 101 | service_1 | res_json |
| 101 | service_2 | res_json |
| 101 | service_3 | res_json |

I need to write a SQL Server query that returns results for services 1 & 2 (but not 3) for each app_id in one row. The desired result looks like this:

| app_id | service_1_res | service_2_res |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | res_json | res_json |
| 101 | res_json | res_json |

My best effort returns the result twice for each app_id (I guess because of the where clause as I select two rows for each app_id).

```
select
     t.application_id,
     ts1.result as service_1_res,
     ts2.result as service_2_res
from mytable t
left join mytable ts1 on t.app_id = ts1.app_id and ts1.service_name = 'service_1'
left join mytable ts2 on t.app_id = ts2.app_id and ts2.service_name = 'service_2'
where t.service_name in ('service_1', 'service_2')
```

I get this:

| app_id | service_1_res | service_2_res |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | res_json | res_json |
| 100 | res_json | res_json |
| 101 | res_json | res_json |
| 101 | res_json | res_json |

May be some kind of nested query could help.

Comment: look up PIVOT.  this should help you

Answer (score 0):

```
create table mytable (
    app_id int,
    service_name varchar(50),
    result varchar(50)
)

insert mytable 
values 
  (100, 'service_1', 'res_json')
, (100, 'service_2', 'res_json')
, (100, 'service_3', 'res_json')
, (101, 'service_1', 'res_json')
, (101, 'service_2', 'res_json')
, (101, 'service_3', 'res_json')

select app_id
, min(case
    when service_name = 'service_1' then result
  end) as service_1
, min(case
    when service_name = 'service_2' then result
  end) as service_2

from mytable

group by app_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9b97c6d2a38d82fa9ddca6580e3255b1

Comment: This works, thanks! But using min, when you are not actually looking for the minimum value is a bit confusing.

Comment: `MIN` just makes that an aggregated column so you can group by `app_id`.  I assume there will be only one distinct value of `result` returned for each combination of `app_id` and `service_name`.  If that's not true, you'll need some different rules specified in your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query. Produces the desired result.

```
select t2.app_id,
   max(case when service_name = 'service_1' then result end) as service_1_res,
   max(case when service_name = 'service_2' then result end) as service_2_res
from
  (select app_id
   from tb1
   where tb1.service_name in ('service_1', 'service_2')
   group by app_id
   having count(app_id) > 1) t1
join
tb1 t2 on t1.app_id = t2.app_id
where t2.service_name not in ('service_3')
group by t2.app_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via Pivot. The solution can be accessed at this link- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df2d1/4

```
select * from 
(
  select app_id, service_name, result
  from myTable
) as mt
pivot
(
  max(result)
  for [service_name] in (service_1, service_2)
) as pt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot san_raj. I like your answer. But I actually had another 'constraint' in my task that I didn't mention in the question (as it seemed unimportant at that time). For each service I need to get a value from json (result) and the 'route' inside json is different for each service. But I believe now I can figure it out myself.